# Adding secondary IP to Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, route, ipv4

I have primary IP address aa.bb.53.34 on my Ubuntu Server 16.04 on eno1 interface. I want to add additional IP address from another network xx.yy.95.4 to the same machine and make this machine accessible by both IPs. I did following command:

```
ip addr add xx.yy.95.4/32 dev eno1
```

But server is still not pinged via secondary IP. What should I also do to make server be accessible by secondary IP?

Output:

```
#ip addr

inet aa.bb.53.34/32 scope global eno1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet xx.yy.95.4/32 scope global eno1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

file `/etc/network/interfaces` does not exist

```
#route -vn

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         aa.bb.53.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
xx.yy.95.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eno1
```

Provider says IP address `xx.yy.95.4` uses `xx.yy.95.1` gateway and netmask is `255.255.255.224`

Comment: If you use /32 address, it is only known from the server itself.

Comment: @Dom I tried to use `xx.yy.95.4/27` too (netmask is 255.255.255.224) with no effect. Also `aa.bb.53.34` is printed as /32 and this IP is accessible from outside

Comment: Are you sure that the entity that gave you the IP address has set up routing properly for the IP address?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen do you mean that adding secondary IP by `ip addr` is enough for accessing server from outside by secondary IP?

Comment: No, I mean that the provider has to set up proper routing for the secondary IP address so that traffic can reach your server with that IP address.

Comment: Provider told they did all set ups. I just want to know what should I do to see my server by additional IP from outside